# Does bachelor degree of computer science required ECA?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, canada

I need help with the above question does bachelor degree of computer science from Egypt requires ECA (Education Credential Assessment ) to go Canada ?

Comment: Are you applying for Express Entry for the Federal Skilled Worker Program (FSWP) or want Comprehensive Ranking System (CRS) points for your education?

Answer (score 4):

As you haven't clarified, here's an overview of Canada's Education Credential Assessment and how to obtain it.

> An [**Educational Credential Assessment (ECA)**](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/assessment.asp) is used to verify that your foreign degree, diploma, certificate (or other proof of your credential) is valid and equal to a Canadian one.
>
> **Who needs an ECA?**
>
> If you have a Canadian degree, diploma or certificate, you do not need to get an ECA for that credential.
>
> You will need to get an ECA for your foreign degree, diploma or certificate if:
>
> a. you want to be considered for the Federal Skilled Worker Program (FSWP) under Express Entry, and
>
> - you are a principal applicant, and
> - you got your education outside Canada, or
>
> b. you want to receive Comprehensive Ranking System (CRS) points for your foreign education
>
> - for yourself as an Express Entry candidate, or
> - for your spouse or common-law partner coming with you to Canada.
>
> To be eligible under a) or to get points under b) you must include ECA results as part of your Express Entry profile.
>
> The ECA report **must** show that your completed foreign credential (degree, diploma or certificate) is equal to a **completed** Canadian secondary school (high school) or post-secondary credential.
>
> You must submit an ECA for all levels of completed foreign education you want us to consider. It is up to you to decide which credentials to have assessed by a designated organization.
>
> Depending on your case, you may want to have both your secondary and post-secondary credentials assessed, and not just your highest completed foreign credential. You will not get any points for your foreign education under the CRS in Express Entry or be eligible under the FSWP if the result on your ECA report does not match at least one of the results in the [conversion table](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/eca-conversion.asp).
>
> **Note:** An ECA can give you early feedback on how your credentials compare to those in Canada. It may also help when you are looking for a job. But, being assessed does not guarantee that:
>
> - you will get a job in your field or at a certain level,
>     your work experience and professional credentials are automatically recognized in Canada, or
> - you will be licensed to practice in a regulated profession.
>
> **[Where can I get an Educational Credential Assessment (ECA)?](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/assessment.asp)**
>
> We have a list of “designated” organizations that can assess your education. This means we recognize and accept their assessments. They will create a report that tells you what your education is equal to in Canada.
>
> You must use one of the organizations listed below. You can visit their websites to find out more about the services each provides and their costs.
>
> We only accept assessments issued on or after the date the organizations were designated to do ECA reports for immigration purposes (see below).
>
> If you got a report before that date, contact the organization to see if they will re-issue it.
>
> **Assessment of most foreign education**
>
> [Comparative Education Service: University of Toronto School of Continuing Studies](http://learn.utoronto.ca/international-professionals/comparative-education-service-ces) (Date designated: April 17, 2013)
>
> [International Credential Assessment Service of Canada](http://www.icascanada.ca/fsw) (Date designated: April 17, 2013)
>
> [World Education Services](http://www.wes.org/fswp) (Date designated: April 17, 2013)
>
> [International Qualifications Assessment Service](http://www.alberta.ca/iqas-immigration.aspx) (Date designated: August 6, 2015) and
>
> [International Credential Evaluation Service](http://www.bcit.ca/ices/eca/) (Date designated: August 6, 2015)
>
> Most people will be able to choose one of these to do their ECA. If you are not sure, contact the organization using the information on their website.
>
> If an organization is not on this list, we can’t accept assessments from them.